# How come Thymeleaf tables creates a gap?

Tags: thymeleaf

Why does my Thyme leaf creates such a big gap when I use the following code below.

```
BAD/WARNING
</h3>
<h3>
APPLICATION PROCESSING
</h3>
<table class="tablebad">
    <tr>
        <th> Status </th>
        <th> HostName </th>
        <th> Process Name </th>
        <th> Process Count </th>
    </tr>
        <tr th:each="DartModel, iterStat : ${countlist}">
        <td th:if ="${DartModel.Status == 'BAD'}" th:text="${DartModel.Status}"></td>
         <td th:if="${DartModel.Status == 'BAD'}" th:text="${DartModel.host}"></td>
        <td th:if="${DartModel.Status == 'BAD'}"  th:text="${DartModel.processName}"></td>
        <td th:if="${DartModel.Status == 'BAD'}"  th:text="${DartModel.processCount}"></td>
         </tr>

</table>


<h3>
APPLICATION PROCESSING
</h3>

<table class="tableok">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Status </th>
        <th> HostName </th>
        <th> Process Name </th>
        <th> Process Count </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="DartModel, iterStat : ${countlist}">
        <td th:if="${DartModel.Status == 'OK'}" th:text ="${DartModel.Status}"></td>
         <td th:if="${DartModel.Status == 'OK'}" th:text="${DartModel.host}"></td>
        <td th:if="${DartModel.Status == 'OK'}" th:text="${DartModel.processName}"></td>
        <td th:if="${DartModel.Status == 'OK'}" th:text="${DartModel.processCount}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Result**
[image: Output]

and under this will be all my data printed out with the status of "OK". I am ultimately trying to sort the data based on value. I tried working with javascript/jquery but it was too complicated. I found a way to split the data rows based on values. If values is "BAD" display table above vice versa to values with "OK"
Am I doing this wrong? I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are putting the `th:if` on the `<td>` elements instead of the `<tr>`.  This means that your html looks something like this (where you have several empty rows between each non-empty row.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>BAD</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>

    <tr>
        <td>BAD</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

You should just move the `th:if` to the `<tr>` element, like so:

```
<table class="tablebad">
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>HostName</th>
        <th>Process Name</th>
        <th>Process Count</th>
    </tr>

    <tr th:each="DartModel, iterStat : ${countlist}" th:if="${DartModel.Status == 'BAD'}">
        <td th:text="${DartModel.Status}" />
        <td th:text="${DartModel.host}" />
        <td th:text="${DartModel.processName}" />
        <td th:text="${DartModel.processCount}" />
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow thank you!, but why does it cause empty rows when I place it under <td> tag? Thanks again!

Comment: I explained it in the beginning of my answer.  If you put it on the `<td>` instead of `<tr>`, you have a bunch of empty table rows between each row of data.

Comment: Is it possible to use this logic on the div tag? Show div if Stats = "Critical"